# How to write a rest Request for file conversion

Tags: javascript, rest, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

Im using a file conversion web service, doxument.com to convert files to pdf.This is the syntax given by doxument. How to i create a rest request out of this using javascript for my windows store app.

```
 GET /docs/{$id}.{$format}[?callback=http://yourapp.com/listen.php
```

Answer (score 0):

From the URL you call, this conversion service has a callback URL to return the conversion result which means it is designed for Web Application rather than the Client Application like windows store app.
You may need to ask the the service provider if they have a conversion API for client app.